# Why do I know that if there are only two right cosets, then they must have the following form?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have an understanding problem.

> If $H<G$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ such that $card(G/H)=2$ then $H$ is normal in $G$.

My problem is the following. So I know that there are only two right cosets, but I thought that therefore $G/H=\{g_1H, g_2H\}$. In the solution they wrote $G/H=\{H, aH\}$ for $a\not\in H$.
And I don't see why one can immediately say this. Could someone explain it to me please?

Thanks for your help

Comment: $H$ is always a left as well as a right coset, so the other must not be $H$.

Comment: Sorry I don't see why $H$ is always a coset

Comment: Is it because $1^{-1}y\in H$ for all $y\in H$ and thus $H$ itself is a coset?

Comment: It’s just $eH$.

Comment: Yes I mean $eH=H$ that's clear but is it only because $e$ needs to be in one equivalence class and if we take $e\in bH$ for some other $b$ then it doesn't matter because $e\sim b$ and thus $bH=eH=H$ so we always can take $e$ as the representative of its class?

Comment: Yes, you always have that choice no matter what.

Comment: ah perfect thanks!